# Change current branch and keep local changes

Tags: git

I'm on branch `a`. I want to make a commit on branch `b`, so that someone who clones branch `b` has the same working directory as I have now.

Stashing the current changes does not work because in some cases this results in a conflict.

I'm looking for the equivalent of making a temporary copy of the working directory, calling `git checkout -f b`, deleting all files, copying the temporary directory to the project directory and making a commit.

Comment: Commit your changes on branch a; checkout branch b; git pull origin/a --force; git reset HEAD~1; do your commit; git push --force; checkout branch a again; git reset HEAD~1; and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git reset --soft if your friend. If you want the revision after B to be the way you have on the working tree (uncommitted as of now), you can do this:

```
git checkout --detach # disconnect from A
git reset --soft b # set the branch pointer to whatever revision B is pointing to.... Your working tree will be unaffected
git add . # add everything to index
git commit -m "revision after B that made it look the way I had it where I was working"
# if you like everything, move b branch to this revision and push
git branch -f b
git checkout b
git push some-remote b
```

That should do.

Answer (score 1):

Any commit essentially *is* "a temporary copy of the working directory".

The "changes between" you refer to are in fact produced for you from the snapshots when you `git show <commit>` for example.

That why it's a bit difficult to gie a straightforward answer your question. Let's try these two possible paths :

---

**With history rewrite of branch `b`**

If you want a commit on branch `b` reflecting the exact state on branch `a` at this very moment, why not just point directly branch b where it should. Like this :

```
# get the uncommited changes on the branch
git commit -am "Useful message"

# point b where a is now
git branch -f b a

# instead of forcing the branch we could merge with a strategy ours
# but it's hard to tell what you need from your description alone

# reset a to its previous state
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Initial state :

```
C1---C2 <<< a <<< HEAD # with a dirty tree, uncommited changes

      ? <<< b # (you didn't mention where b was pointing)
```

Result afterwards

```
C1---C2 <<< a <<< HEAD
     \
      C3 <<< b # where your last (previously uncommited) changes are
```

As it rewrites history of the branch, it should be considered carefully, and probably ruled out if the branch is shared. Still, it does what you asked for : "someone who clones branch b has the same working directory as I have now".

---

**Without rewriting history of branch `b`**

To avoid rewriting the history of branch `b`, an alternative is to merge a into b with a strategy which will take everything from `a` side, not only conflicting parts. It would go like this :

```
# we work on a copy of branch a
git checkout -b a-copy a

# get the uncommited changes on the branch
git commit -am "Useful message"

# proceed with the merge, taking nothing from b
git merge -s ours b

# we now reflect the merge on b, and this is a fast-forward
git checkout b
git merge a-copy

# no further need for the working copy of a
git branch -D a-copy
```

And `a` doesn't need to be reset because it didn't move at any point.

After the first commit :

```
C1---C2 <<< a
     \
      C3 <<< a-copy <<< HEAD

      o <<< b (anywhere in the tree)
```

After the first merge :

```
C1---C2 <<< a
     \
      C3 (same state as a, plus the previously uncommited changes)
       \
        C4 <<< a-copy <<< HEAD (the merge taking only C3 side)
       /
      o <<< b (anywhere in the tree)
```

End state :

```
C1---C2 <<< a
     \
      C3 (same state as a, plus the previously uncommited changes)
       \
        C4 <<< b <<< HEAD
       /
      o
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way that keeps the history of the branch `b`? So that just one commit is added.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `git stash` *does* save the current work-tree.  The problem is that the *way* it saves it is not directly suitable to your needs.  There is also a secondary problem, which *may* be a very nasty problem but may instead be quite minor.  See the caveat below.  But in the end, you *may* be able to use `git stash` to do what you want.

#### What to know

First, remember that Git does not make commits from your work-tree (your working directory) at all—and that commits are complete *snapshots* of all files.  They are snapshots that are made from the *index*, not from the work-tree.  The files in a new commit are those that are in the index *right now*.

(Remember also that the index is that thing that other parts of Git call the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*.  It holds one copy of every file that will go into the *next* commit.  That copy is initially the copy taken from the *current* commit, except for some edge cases noted in [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)

If your work-tree differs from your index, and you want to snapshot your work-tree, you need to `git add` each file, overwriting the copy *in* the index, before you can commit this.  This, of course, destroys any careful staging you have done *in* your index.

But that's why `git stash` really makes *two* commits:

- One commit saves your current index state, as a new commit that is not on any branch.  Now it's safe to destroy the index state.
- The second commit saves your current work-tree, as a commit with two parents: the index commit, and the current commit.  To *get* that commit made, Git *replaces* all of the files in the index with their work-tree variants (because Git makes commits from the index, not from the work-tree).<sup>1</sup>

(There's actually a third optional commit to hold untracked or untracked-plus-ignored files.  If that commit exists, it is the third parent of the work-tree commit.  Usually it just doesn't exist though.)

Having made these two commits, `git stash` updates `refs/stash` to remember the work-tree commit `w`'s hash ID.  That commit remembers the index commit `i`'s hash ID, as well as the current commit's hash ID:

```
...--o--o--T   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
 \         |\
  \        i-w   <-- refs/stash
   \
    o--A   <-- b
```

Then `git stash` runs `git reset --hard`, so that your index and work-tree go back to matching commit `T`.  I've highlighted one other commit `A`, as pointed-to by some other branch `b`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, `git stash` makes commit `w` using a second, auxiliary / temporary index, just in case something goes wrong.  It can just abandon the temporary index in that case.  Making index commit `i` is very easy though, as the plumbing command `git write-tree` does all the work.

---

#### Making use of Git's stash commit

Remember the caveat here: `git stash` essentially just does `git add` on all the files that are *already* in the index.  Any untracked files, including any untracked-and-ignored files, aren't in commit `w` at all.  They're just sitting in your work-tree.  That's true *even if*, had you done `git checkout A` to get to commit `A`, some of those files *would have been* copied into your index.  (Of course in this case you would generally have seen a complaint that Git needed to overwrite some untracked file, first.)

Anyway, except for this one big caveat, the stash commit `w` has, in its *snapshot*, exactly the snapshot you say you would like to be added just past commit `A`.

You can, now that this snapshot exists, tell Git to make a new commit `B` that has `A` as its parent and `w`'s *tree* as its snapshot.  This needs one Git plumbing command:

```
git commit-tree -p refs/heads/b refs/stash^{tree}
```

That is, we use the name `refs/heads/b` (branch `b`, pointing to commit `A`) to tell Git what the *parent* hash ID should be for our new commit.  We use `refs/stash^{tree}` to tell Git what the *tree* (snapshot) should be for our new commit.  Git reads standard input to collect a log message—if you like, add `-m <message>` or `-F <file>` to supply a message, or send one to the standard input:

```
echo some message | git commit-tree -p refs/heads/b refs/stash^{tree}
```

The result is:

```
...--o--o--T   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
 \         |\
  \        i-w   <-- refs/stash
   \
    o--A   <-- b
        \
         B
```

where new commit `B` has the same snapshot as stash commit `w`.

The `git commit-tree` command *prints out* the hash ID of the new commit.  You'll need to grab this—perhaps into a shell variable—and then most likely set some name, such as `refs/heads/b`, to remember this commit.  For instance:

```
hash=$(git commit-tree -p refs/heads/b refs/stash^{tree})
git update-ref -m "add stashed work-tree commit" refs/heads/b $hash
```

giving:

```
...--o--o--T   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
 \         |\
  \        i-w   <-- refs/stash
   \
    o--A--B   <-- b
```

That is, new commit `b` is now the tip of existing branch `b`.  The *snapshot* in `B` is that in `w`; they're automatically shared.  The *log message* in `B` is whatever you gave to `git commit-tree`.  The *hash ID* of `B` is now stored in `b`, and `B`'s parent is `A`, so that this new commit is on branch `b`, just as you wanted.

Now that all of *that* is done, you will want to restore your index and work-tree, which `git stash` threw out, but first saved in those two commits.  To do that, use `git stash pop --index`.  The `--index` is important: it compares your current index to `i` and uses the differences to restore your index.<sup>2</sup>  Then it compares your current work-tree to `w` and uses the differences to restore your work-tree from `w`.  The `pop` part of this then discards the `i-w` commits and if there were other stashed commits, makes `refs/stash` remember the correct one.

Hence, ignoring all the places where things could go *wrong* and all the appropriate error checking, the following command sequence *might* do what you want, depending on just what is is you want:

```
git stash push   # and make sure it does something
hash=$(echo automatic commit of work-tree |
    git commit-tree -p refs/heads/b refs/stash^{tree})
git update-ref -m "add stashed work-tree commit" refs/heads/b $hash
git stash pop --index
```

This is entirely untested (and has some bad failure modes, especially the one where `git stash push` says that there is nothing to save and refuses to do anything at all).

---

<sup>2</sup>This is an inefficient way of just reading `i` directly into the index, but it achieves the same goal.  The same holds for the `w` step.

Comment: I'll also note that except for the way it totally ruins your current index, it's much more *efficient* to just add everything and commit (using `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree` and `git update-ref` to put the commit onto branch `b`). You can fix the former problem by using a temporary index, the way `git stash` does. But that wouldn't illustrate why you can use `git stash` to get what you want. :-)